# MySQL procedure to find ships in battle given a country. relations inside

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a procedure in which given a battle name, produce two countries that were in that battle. (If there are not exactly two countries produce NULL for both country)

The first part of the procedure is non-trivial to me (I think)

```
SELECT ship FROM outcomes WHERE battle = inBattle AS t1;
SELECT DISTINCT class FROM ships WHERE name IN t1 AS t2;
SELECT DISTINCT country FROM classes WHERE class IN t2;
```

I think this will give me a table with a list of distinct countries in the specific battle. My problem comes in when I try to do the second part, if not exactly two countries are found produce NULL for both countries.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE findCountriesInBattle( in inBattle VARCHAR(50) )
BEGIN
    SELECT ship FROM outcomes WHERE battle = inBattle AS t1;
    SELECT DISTINCT class FROM ships WHERE name IN t1 AS t2;
    SELECT DISTINCT country FROM classes WHERE class IN t2 AS t3;
IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t3 < 2 OR SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t3 > 2)
    [show NULL, NULL]; << Line 1
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM t3; << Line 2
END IF;
END;
//
```

How might I properly write Line 1 and Line 2? Are the other lines right?

RELATIONS:

```
classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)
ships( name, class, launched)
battles(name, date)
outcomes(ship, battle, result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use table joins to simplify the basic query. You can get a list of distinct countries for a given battle with one SELECT query joining the 3 tables together.

Since you are writing a stored procedure, one straightforward approach is to select the count into a local variable first, then use a conditional to display the country names or the nulls as appropriate.

Here's an example based on your source code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE findCountriesInBattle( in inBattle VARCHAR(50) )
BEGIN
   DECLARE v_country_count INT;

  -- count the countries involved in the battle
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT classes.country)
  INTO V_COUNTRY_COUNT
  FROM outcomes
  INNER JOIN ships ON ships.name = outcomes.ship
  INNER JOIN classes ON classes.class = ships.class
  WHERE outcomes.battle = inBattle;

  IF (v_country_count = 2)
  THEN
    -- if it was exactly 2, output the names
    SELECT DISTINCT classes.country
    FROM outcomes
    INNER JOIN ships ON ships.name = outcomes.ship
    INNER JOIN classes ON classes.class = ships.class
    WHERE outcomes.battle = inBattle; 
  ELSE
    -- otherwise, output NULL,NULL
    SELECT null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null;  
  END IF;
END;
//
```

Comment: The biggest thing I hate about trying to learn this is that I can understand that all perfectly, I just can't type/flow it put as easily as if I were writing C++/Java. I guess its lack of syntax knowledge...